# Вывод postgresql в jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Есть сущность User, для нее в контроллере написан метод, который помещает имеющихся пользователей в список.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<User> getUserList() {
    return userService.getUserList();
}
```

В БД postgresql есть соответствующая таблица users.

Задача - сделать вывод данных из БД в jsp.
Я так понимаю это нужно сделать через rest запрос.

Но не могу понять как это должно выглядеть в jsp.

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

REST тут вообще не при чём. Для передачи модели в представление используйте другую форму перегруженного метода контроллера:

**Контроллер**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUserList(ModelMap model) {
    // Передаём в контекст шаблона переменную users
    // содержащую список пользователей
    model.addAttribute("users", userService.getUserList());
    // Возвращаем имя шаблона (имя jsp-файла без расширения)
    return "users"; 
}
```

**users.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
          <!-- Проходим в цикле по элементам списка users -->
          <c:forEach var="user" items="users">
            <tr>
                <!-- Неявный вызор метода getUsername() экземпляра User -->
                <td>${user.username}</td>
                <td>${user.email}</td>
            </tr>
          </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но допустима ли логика в jsp? это же view, стоит задача использовать интерфейс для вывода данных.

Comment: Циклы, условные выражение, обращение к данным и их форматирование нельзя считать выносом логики в представление. Но хорошо, что вы об этом задумываетесь.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)